# Why is this object return undefined value?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which returns the below object (see screenshot). Nevertheless, I am not able to deconstruct the city, postcode, state, or country, while it works for lat and lng, any reason why?

```
        const locationObj = {
            error:false,
            errorMessage:'',
            lat:'',
            lng:'',
            city:'',
            state:'',
            country:'',
            postcode:'',
        }
        const res =  await requestUserLocation(locationObj)
        if(res.error){
            return null
        }
        console.log('this is the response',res)
        console.log('this is the response city',res.city)
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the definition of `requestUserLocation`

Comment: The console output indicates `res.city` was updated after you did the first `console.log`. Notice that the first line has `city: ''`, you only see `London` when you expand it later.

Comment: this is not reproductible